# input type="file" is it possible to style it to ONLY text like "upload"

Tags: css, input, upload

as the tittle says, is it possible to style a `<input type="file">` to only show text like `"Upload"` without the button and the target file showing :)

i've tryed to google but all the answer doesnt cut it, the only answer that came close to what i wanted was done with javascript div trigger that would trigger.(click) on the input `<input type="file">` but as it was pointed out that browser/mobile phones would take this as a "attack" and wouldn't allow the $_POST!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [CustomInputFile](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) use Bootstrap its more easy to customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by mocking the input element and binding an event listener to a div or whatever you would like to use like this:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="upload"/>
    <div id="button">Upload</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#upload{
  display: none; 
}

#button{ 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("upload").click();
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/12Lp66p2/

Comment: the only answer that came close to what i wanted was done with javascript div trigger that would trigger.(click) on the input <input type="file"> but as it was pointed out that browser/mobile phones would take this as a "attack" and wouldn't allow the $_POST!

Comment: ah sorry I misunderstood that part of the question but I will leave my answer up because my question is a relevant answer to the heading of your question